# How to set maximum limit of checked elements in MD-selection-list Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-forms

i have md-selection-list with `*ngFor` of some tags, for example `[sport,relax,..]`

The tags are stored in `this.tags`, and the selected tags are stored in `this.tab`

I want to prevent user for selecting more than 5 tags. So if user select 5th item, there should be some alert, and user can type different tag only when unchecked some of checked items.

I start with this code, but it isn't working. I try to disable this "check" icon on list-item, and then not add the item to this.tab until the user have <5 tags stored. The problem is I can't disable this "check" icon.

This is the code:

```
clickedOnRow(row){

if(this.tab.length > 5){

  this.tags.forEach((item,index) =>{
    if(item.text == row.text){

      this.selectedList.nativeElement.children[index].children[0].children[1].classList.remove('mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked')
      this.selectedList.nativeElement.children[index].children[0].children[1].className = 'mat-pseudo-checkbox'
    }
  });

}else{
  this.tab.push(row.text);
}
}
```

What do You think about this? How to solve this problem? Maybe some other solution, easier? is for this problem?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable unselected options when the selected count reaches some limit,

```
<mat-selection-list #shoes>
  <mat-list-option
      #shoe
      *ngFor="let shoeType of typesOfShoes"
      [disabled]="shoes.selectedOptions.selected.length > 2 && !shoe.selected">
    {{shoeType}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta12-ehlsjg?file=app/app.component.html)

--

Updated example that shows an alert when the final option is selected

[EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta12-txr2qx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

To be honest, I was lazy about this and there are likely better ways, but it works. Also selection list has an improved `selectionChange` event that will be introduced in the next release. A click handler is the best you can do right now, I think.

Comment: WOW, thats nice :)
But, how can i implement some alert that the items reached a limit? So how to tell typescript that this disabled-case was triggerd

Comment: Updated with another example

Comment: :D it' s pretty nice and so simple, I don't know this way of solving this problem. Thank You very much!