# How to use 'selected' property of Angular material select (multiple) in reactive Angular 6 form

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-forms

I'm new to Angular. I want get all selected values from the Material Select Control before submitting form and I also want to implement that user can not select more than 3 options. I have tried in many ways and I also could not find the right way to implement this 'selected' property of 'Select' control.

Here is the link of detail page of select control api

https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Comment: What are we supposed to do with that link? The issue is in your code, assuming you have some attempt to do this (which you should). Please show us your code and where you are facing an issue. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a multi select example on this component, instead of API tab click the examples tab. Here is their stackblitz link to the example.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/xamkeymbbvvk?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts

Using their example I believe **this.toppings.value** will get the value in your component.

For limiting user to only selecting 3, here is an example of disabling the field once the length reaches the limit of 2, I am sure something like this would work.

[How to set maximum limit of checked elements in MD-selection-list Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46768773/how-to-set-maximum-limit-of-checked-elements-in-md-selection-list-angular2)